# save list order in database?

Tags: sql

I have a list with values from the db, and with jquery ui I can change the sorting order of the list witch is great!

But now I wonder how I can save the changed order to the db? With a do until, but how?

This is what I got so far.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY u.avd_id DESC;"
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)


if saveList="saveList" then

userIdet = session("user_id")
sql3="delete from links where userId="& userIdet &";"
set rs3=conn.execute(sql3)

response.write " $('li','#myList').each(function(i,li) { "


sql= "INSERT INTO links SET headline='"& headline &"',datum='"& datum &"',links_adress='"& links_adress &"', userId=" & userId & " ;"
conn.Execute (sql)


response.write" })"

response.redirect("links.asp")

end if
```

I would really need some help, thanks! /Claes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is able to choose and save how the list is sorted, then you should have a displayOrder column in your table. When the user saves the changes, just do an update on the displayOrder column for each item in your list. Then your select statement will ORDER BY displayOrder, rather than by u.avd_id.

Or if you want to delete and re-add like you are doing, you need something like this:

```
response.write " $('li','#myList').each(function(i,li) { "

int i = 1;

sql= "INSERT INTO links SET headline='"& headline &"',datum='"& datum &"',links_adress='"& links_adress &"', userId=" & userId & ", avd_id=" & i & " ;"

i++;

conn.Execute (sql)

response.write" })"
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but it doesnt really matter witch way you go, the thing is I need a counter i and a do until i is finished and inside that one I insert or update...something like this, but how is the question :-)

Comment: In the loop that you have, you need to set avd_id to set the sortId (avd_id in this case) to each item as it is added to the database. Editing my answer to include code.

Comment: Thanks Gendolkari I have to test it tomorrow, its been a long day. Cheers Claes

Answer (score -1):

I would first ask myself if there is a better JavaScript library that better ties HTML/UI to the backend database to make my life easier.